# Story where humans evolve into consciousness encased in glass, ends with a boy breaking the glass tubes?

Tags: story-identification, evolution

My friend told me about a science fiction story he read where humans evolved into consciousness contained within glass tubes, and at the end of the story a boy found the glass tubes in a cave or something and was breaking them for fun. I've looked around, but can't seem to find this story.

Comment: Do you know approximately when and where he read it? Whether it was in a magazine or a book?

Comment: what exactly entails "evolved into consciousness" in this story? Maybe one of these [People Jars](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/PeopleJars) examples fits the bill.

Answer (score 2):

The Matched trilogy by Allyson Braithwaite Condie mentions glass containers with the essence of people that have passed away. These containers are stored in a hidden cave and disturbed (retained and/or vandalized) by the protagonists of the story.